# Is the Rails 2 ActionController::Base.session[:secret] redundant with Rails 3 Main::Application.config.secret_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

Is the Rails 2 ActionController::Base.session[:secret] redundant with Rails 3 Main::Application.config.secret_token?

I'm using activerecord sessions -- I still need the secret for my session cookie, right?

Is the same secret used for form submission validations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set the secret directly on `ActionController::Base.session` anymore. Use `ApplicationName.config.secret_token`.

If you intend to use Rails' unobtrusive Javascript functionality, read up on the new `csrf_meta_tag` view helper: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper/csrf_meta_tag